# OpenSLL::SLL and libssl.a - > How are these linked to each other?

Tags: c++11

I am using Paho-MQTT-c and OpenSSL in a project. This was working a week ago.

Now I cannot link the Paho with the OpenSLL library. It cannot find OpenSSL::SSL

(And the crypto as well but, I guess, that will be the same issue)

Since I had a working version before, something has changed, So I put in some message() in the cmake scripts. ( My code has not changed, but there is something different)

`find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)`

This works since I get a valid return on both cross as native compile

`CROSS - /opt/arm/arm20210202/arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/libssl.a

NATIVE - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a
`
So the the library is found in the correct place.
But building the project results in this

`BOTH /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenSSL::SSL: No such file or directory`

Since the MQTT project uses OpenSSL::SSL  as a reference. (which worked)
I am trying to find the relation between

OpenSSL::SSL and libssl.a

The libssl.a or something should connect to OpenSLL::SSL. Can anybody tell me how this is related ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED) will run a makefile `FindOpenSSL.cmake`
localed at `/snap/clion/260/bin/cmake/linux/x64/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/`

If this is successful it will create an alias named OpenSSL::SSL

So that is how the OpenSSL::SSL is connected to libssl (and libcrypt)